# Quering a webpage on client side

Tags: html, browser

I want to extract data form a web page that contains simple html tables. Now I only want to extract data from specific columns. Now I assume the only way to do this is via using client side (browser) code or technique in the "Inspect element" utility in browsers such as Firebug...Anyone know how to do that?

I suspect that you have to be able to do this by using the 'console' function in the browser's Inspect Element tool

Thank you

Comment: Is this one-time operation? You can use Excel for this. Just try to "Get External Data from Web". Possibly this approach can be scripted in macro to reuse it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. YEah kind of a one time approach, but I'll like to re-use it. The Macros, do i set it up in Excel?